# Query multiple SQL Servers in One query

Tags: sql-server, command-line

I am trying to set up a query that will grab the Windows version of each SQL Server I have and throw it into a table. I have the query that grabs the version but I think there is a better way to get the information needed than connecting to each indiviual server one by one to run the query. I am not opposed to using XP_cmdshell I am just wondering if there is a way to run one query that will grab the version of each Windows OS I have on the sql servers. Also I do have a list of servers to use.

EDIT: I know I wil have to in some way touch each server. I would just like a way to get around having the RDP to each server and open SQL server and query it or haveing to connect to each server within sql server and running the query one by one.

All I have right now code wise is a simple INSERT STATEMENT I get here and I draw a blank on where to go next of even hoe to tackle the problem. The table below has two columns ServerName and Win_Ver ServerName is already populated with all the servers I have.

```
INSERT INTO mtTable
(Win_Ver)

SELECT @@Version
```

Comment: can you post the code you currently have?  also, is your question about improving the efficiency of your query by a means other than connecting to each server?  because there isn't going to be another way -- you'll have to query each server in some form in order to get the info.

Comment: Umm that is NOT the windows version of each server, it is the sql server version info. You will have to run that query on each sql server instance. There really is no way around it.

Comment: Check out LINKED SERVERS and Remote Procedure Calls. The linked server will let you query different Sql servers, but I think the @@version stays local unless you use the Remote Procedure Call (basically, execute your query on the remote server). I might be wrong about that, so double-check.

Comment: What version(s) of SQL Server are you using? How many servers do you have? Does the number of servers fluctuate very often?

Comment: I have a mixture between 2008 - 2012 and I have roughly 112 servers.

Comment: @BrianStork and Wes: Yes, `@@` variables and built-in meta-data functions are local, but RPC will let you execute `sp_executesql` on the Linked Server that would run those locally on the remote server. There is also the [sys.dm_os_windows_info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204565.aspx) DMV that can be queried against the remote system, but that was introduced in 2008 R2, so not helpful if 2005 and/or 2008 is in the mix.

Comment: I think with 112 servers is a bit unwieldy for creating Linked Servers for just this singular / minor purpose. What are you going to do with the output? Does it need to be a table?

Comment: There is table we are keeping with all of our DB server Statistics. We periodically get asked to produce these statistics and it would be easier to just go into a table and pull it out instead of going into the server and getting all the info like CPU, RAM, Number of cores stuff like that and one of the metrics we have is the windows OS version.

Comment: Wes, I just posted an answer that should work and is the best I can think of for built-in functionality. But, there might be an even better / easier way. I am currently beta-testing a new product that is designed to do exactly this type of thing (i.e. query multiple servers and aggregate the results to a single single table). If you are interested in trying it out, you can contact me via the "Contact Us" page at the URL in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Given that:

- there are "roughly 112 servers"
- the servers being a "mixture between 2008 - 2012"
- "There is table we are keeping with all of our DB server Statistics."
- and "We periodically get asked to produce these statistics"

one option is to cycle through that table of servers using a cursor, and for each one, execute `xp_cmdshell` to call `SQLCMD` to run the query. You would use a table variable to capture the result set from SQLCMD as returned by `xp_cmdshell`. Something like:

```
DECLARE @ServerName sysname,
        @Command    NVARCHAR(4000),
        @CommandTemplate NVARCHAR(4000);

DECLARE @Results TABLE ([ResultID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, [Result] NVARCHAR(4000));

SET @CommandTemplate = N'SQLCMD -S {{SERVER_NAME}} -E -h-1 -Q "PRINT @@VERSION;"';

DECLARE srvrs CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD
FOR   SELECT [ServerName]
      FROM ServerStats;

OPEN srvrs;

FETCH NEXT
FROM  srvrs
INTO  @ServerName;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  SET @Command = REPLACE(@CommandTemplate, N'{{SERVER_NAME}}', @ServerName);

  INSERT INTO @Results ([Result])
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command;

  -- Get results via SELECT [Result] FROM @Results ORDER BY [ResultID];
  -- Do something with the data in @Results

  DELETE FROM @Results;

  FETCH NEXT
  FROM  srvrs
  INTO  @ServerName;
END;

CLOSE srvrs;
DEALLOCATE srvrs;
```

And it wouldn't hurt to throw in a TRY / CATCH in there :-).

Even if not the most ideal of solutions, it is at least doesn't require adding 112 Linked Servers, and is dynamic and will adjust to servers being added and removed.

Comment: If you want to do `EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command;`, then `@Command` needs to be `sysname` datatype, not `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. There are better ways to loop than using a cursor. To clean up the output a little, try setting a variable to @@version then PRINTING it instead of just selecting it.

Comment: @BrianStork Thanks for the feedback. **1)** [xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), takes either `NVARCHAR(4000)` or `VARCHAR(8000)`. I couldn't remember if `NVARCHAR` was 4000 or MAX and was hoping that `MAX` would work since DOS commands can be > 4000 chars. Oh well. But `sysname` is an alias for `NVARCHAR(128)` and is used for names of objects, etc. **2)** "better ways to loop than using a cursor" is a myth that has been disproven quite a few times, and **3)** `PRINT` and `SELECT` give the same output, but `PRINT doesn't need `SET NOCOUNT` so I will fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the code however I am getting errors:                                Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
'READONLY' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Must declare the scalar variable "@Commmand".                                                                             I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 to run the query from and I don't know if the commands are specific to a later version or if I am missing something.

Comment: @WesPalmer No, you are not missing anything. The code was an approximation, not exact. But I have now fixed it (3 minor changes), and it works across all versions, possibly including 2000, as there is nothing version specific in there. Well, the ability to do `INSERT...EXEC()` was not possible in SQL Server 2000, but that changed in either 2005 or 2008.

Comment: Sorry but I am getting one more error.                                                                                                            SQLCMD -S <servername>           -E -h-1 -Q "PRINT @@VERSION;"
Msg 214, Level 16, State 201, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'.                                                                                               On the first line above I was printing out the command being used. Sorry I am becoming a little bit of a bother.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out with XM_cmdshell you can't use VARCHAR(MAX) you must use a finite number. Thanks for all of your help this works great.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that the other day. I have just changed both variable declarations. And yer welcome. If it works, please don't ferget to accept :-).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you are able to create a Linked Server that you can query from another server.

On the server you wish to write the query in:

Open the Object Explorer
Go to Server Objects
Right Click Linked Servers and add a New Linked Server

Add the Name of your networked server, select SQL server and make sure to define security roles.

Comment: Thanks I have thoght about that but I should have added that my group frowns apon the use of linked servers because they can break easily.

Comment: I find the best way to add a linked server is to add a sql server login to the server that you are linking to, and in the security section of the link you add that login. I use logins that are specifically for the link between servers.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I can't add linked servers and adding a liked server with some randomly created SQL User is an even worse way to try to fix the problems they can cause.